# Checkbox won't check

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have this code placed in my `gridview_SelectedIndexChanged`, but then the checkbox still won't check. How would I change the codes in a way where in if one of my selected rows in my gridview have the letter `O` on it, the checkbox would automatically check?

```
protected void gvAuto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtSurname.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    txtFN.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    txtOrg.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
    txtAdd.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtPosition.Text= gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtTelNum1.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtTelNum2.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtTelNum3.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtMobileNum.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtEmail1.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[9].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", ""); ;
    txtEmail2.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
    txtEmail3.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[11].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");

    if (gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "") == "")
    {
        cbCategory1.Checked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        cbCategory1.Checked = true;
    }

    txtValidate2.Text = gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[13].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", "");
}
```

Comment: You should add a tag explaining what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test for the value `O` you could shorten this to:

```
//...
cbCategory1.Checked = (gvAuto.SelectedRow.Cells[12].Text == "O");
//...
```

From your question it's a little unclear if `cbCategory1` is a child control of your `GridView` which would require a different solution.

Try to debug and step into your event handler and check if the cell value is read correct.